# Send a string from a python program on one device to a python program on another

Tags: python, user-interface, websocket, messaging

assuming I want to make a program to send a string (message) from one device to another using python, pretty much a messaging app, how would I do that? Right now I'm using a one-drive .txt file to store the message, but not only is it slow, it also needs a manual refresh. Is there any way I can use web-socket to do this?

Current code for the one-drive messaging program:

```
from time import sleep
import socket
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
sending = False

def refresh():
    readMessages()

def clear():
    for widget in win.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

def readMessages():
    sending = False
    clear()
    with open("messageLog.txt", "r") as mLog:
        messages = mLog.readlines()
        if len(messages) > 0:
            for message in messages:
                tk.Label(win, text=message).pack()
        else:
            tk.Label(win, text="No messages!").pack()
    button = tk.Button(win, text="SEND MESSAGE", command=messageInit)
    button2 = tk.Button(win, text="REFRESH", command=refresh)
    button.pack()
    button2.pack()
    sleep(1)

def messageInit():
    sending = True
    clear()
    tk.Label(win, text="Message:").grid(row=0)
    entry = tk.Entry(win)
    entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
    doneButton = tk.Button(win, text="DONE", command=lambda: sendMessage(entry)).grid(row=1)

def sendMessage(entry):
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    with open("messageLog.txt", "r+") as mLog:
        messages = mLog.readlines()
        messages.append(hostname + ": " + entry.get() + "\n")
        messages = "".join(messages)
        mLog.truncate(0)
        mLog.seek(0)
        mLog.write(messages)
    readMessages()

refresh()
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: "How do I" questions don't really belong in here, you can research and show what you've got and tell where you went wrong and we can help you then